# My bottom sheet self expends when I edit the layout in the background

Tags: java, android, self, expand, bottom-sheet

I Have a bottomSheet that is a NestedScrollView, Inside I have a recyclerview.

What bother me is that, whenever the bottom sheet is collapsed and I notifyDataSetChanged() to update recyclerview's item, my bottom sheet pops up on its own. But I want it to keep it collapsed, as my bottom sheet is accessible via a button click (it displays some secondary info)

Have sbdy encounter this ?
Do you want to see my code ?

thank you, you devs :)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of search with different key word, i finally found out that is is due to the usage of :

```
animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

this should be removed.

Credits to : [BottomSheet fly away with visibility change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327849/bottomsheet-fly-away-with-visibility-change)

I keep my answer online to help other have a better change to find help.